# How to get all specific buttons and click on each one with a specific data-id in Cypress

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cypress, selector

I am having trouble selecting buttons on a page which has the same class name, but different data-ids in Cypress.

There are multiple courses with different ids, and I need to loop through each course and click on the `Register` button. There are other buttons on the page (View Course), but I only want to click on the `Register` button.

I tried the code below but no luck in Cypress:

```
cy.get(`.university [data-course-id=${id}] > button`).click()
```

```
cy.get(`.university [data-course-id=“1234”}] > button`).click()
```

Also tried this in Chrome Dev Tools to get a specific button. I need to get each Register button on the page.

```
$('.university [data-course-id=“1234”] > button')
```

But Cypress says it cannot find this element.

What is the issue? How would we select all the Register buttons and click each one?

Thanks for the help!

```html
<div class="university">
  <div class="course" data-course-id="1234">
    <div class="courseTitle">
      <span>Computer Science</span>
       <button>View Course</button>
     </div>
     <button>Register</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  
  <div class="course" data-course-id="bio3">
    <div class="courseTitle">
      <span>Biology</span>
       <button>View Course</button>
     </div>
     <button>Register</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  
  <div class="course" data-course-id="987b">
    <div class="courseTitle">
      <span>English</span>
       <button>View Course</button>
     </div>
     <button>Register</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

cy.get(`.appMovieContainer [data-movie-id=${id}] > button`).click()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this. This will iterate through all the `.course` classes and inside that click on the button with text as Register one by one.

```
cy.get('.course').each(($ele) => {
    cy.wrap($ele).find('button').contains('Register').click()
})
```

OR

```
cy.get('.course').each(($ele) => {
    cy.wrap($ele).find('button').eq(1).click()
})
```

Comment: Just a thought. If it triggers a page render, may be recursion is better.?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with

```js
cy.get(`.university [data-course-id=“1234”}] > button`).click()
```

is

- the rogue `}`, which is probably a typo
- the quote marks around `1234` are not recognized by Cypress.
  Try this out:

```js
expect('“').not.to.eq('"')       // true  
console.log('“'.charCodeAt(0))   // 8220  
console.log('"'.charCodeAt(0))   // 34
```

The correct version is

```js
cy.get('.university [data-course-id="1234"] > button')
```

---

There's nothing wrong with `.each()`, but another approach is to use `:contains()` in the selector

```js
cy.get('.university .course button:contains("Register")')
  .click({multiple: true})                          // "multiple" will click all matching buttons
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `cy.get('[button="Register"]')` and then use `each` method to perform click operation.

[Cypress each](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each#Yields)